# Insert a TikZ picture from an external file

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I tried to search a bit, but i guess my poor English prevented me from finding the answer.

I made a few tikz pictures that i want to use in my report. I made the tikz pictures in separate tex files so i don't have to compile my whole report just to check the image.

But now, when copy pasting the tikz code into my report the image looks different. Some stuff moved or is not in the right position.

I was hoping this could be fixed by instead of putting the tikz code in my report, inserting the tikz.tex file similar to `\include` or `\insert`.

This way i hope my picture will look like it does in the separate file and i will not have to compile it when i compile my report.

I guess this is possible, but i just don't know how and i could not find it. Does anyone know_

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your problem of different results is most likely due to different font sizes or other settings in the picture and main file. This is especially true if you are using `em` or `ex` as placing units. I can't tell more about it without knowing your code.

However, you can avoid this by ensuring identical settings in both files. Should this not be possible you can still compile the external picture to a PDF an include it using `\includegraphics`. There is a small size overhead coming with it, but it should not be an issue. It has actually a nice speed benefit with larger TikZ pictures.

For external TikZ pictures I recommend the following procedure:
Use the `standalone` *class* for the TikZ picture file and then use the `standalone` *package* in the main file. This way you can use `\input` to read the external file while its preamble is ignored or even copied to the main preamble automatically. When the external picture is compiled by its own `standalone` makes sure it is placed on a tight page using the `preview` package. The resulting PDF pictures are very suitable to be included into the main document.
I'm currently working on a new version of `standalone` which gives you an `\includestandalone` with an option if the `.tex` or `.pdf` should be included!

---

#### Update Apr 2012:

The v1.0 of the `standalone` package now provides `\includestandalone` which works like `\includegraphics`, but with `standalone` files (and similar). The package has a `mode=<mode>` option which controls if the standalone source file is compiled with the main document (`mode=tex`) or a PDF version is included as image (`mode=image`). The PDF can also be build if required (`mode=build`, `mode=buildnew` or `mode=buildmissing`).

**An important option for this question** is `obeyclassoptions`, which will try to obey all class option used in the standalone file even if this file is compiled as part of the main document and therefore the standalone preamble is ignored. This means if the external files use `\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}` then a 12pt font size is also used when this file is included (as source code) in the main document.

Comment: Thx for the answer! I will check it out tomorrow (dont have the time now)

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your technical question but maybe you can avoid the problem completely if you use [Qtikz](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language) to check your images or even draw them directly as I usually do.

Comment: Thanks @percusse. I used Qtikz/ktikz before a little bit. It is a very useful program, but I personally like the above way better, especially if you use the picture in several documents.

Comment: @Martin: standalone sounds useful, but does not appear to be in Tex Live 2009 (currently in Debian). If I understand the usage correctly, this makes it possible for the same external tex file either to compile a standalone TikZ picture (say), or to be included in a larger document and compiled as part of that larger document. Support for switching seamlessly between a PDF include and including the latex code directly would be nice, if that is what the latter part of your comment says.

Comment: @Faheem: The package is newer then 2009. You can download `standalone` from [CTAN](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/). Simply run the `.ins` file through `latex` to extract the `.sty` and `.cls` files.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer i tried ur standalone option. Compiling my tex file with the tikz picture works fine. But when i use the `include` function in my mainfile i get this error: `PGF math error: unknown function of` while i dont get this compiling the file with the tikz picture itself. Odd

Comment: @Elmer: You should use `\input` not `\include`. The error might be because you forgot a Tikz libery in the main file?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer that was a typo sorry. I am using `\input` and im sure i didnt forget anything, since i didnt change anything in the external tikz picture. And i can compile the tikz picture itself without any problems.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, I did that. Dumb question - is it a copyright violation to include the sty file in my code repository (license GPL v2 or later). Maybe this should be a separate question; please indicate if so.

Comment: @Faheem: It's under the normal, free LaTeX [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/) license. I don't mind when it is put into a GPLv2 or later code repository.

Comment: @Elmer: I would have to see the source code to see what is wrong. As test simply copy the `{tikzpicture}` environment directly in the main file. If the error is still there it isn't caused by `standalone`.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer then it works fine. No error when copy pasting the code in my mainfile. This is kinda odd.

Comment: @Elmer: Do you mind to show me the source code of that file? My email address would be in the package documentation.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer i will once i have a a free moment. Thx